# Filter either ONLY one property or all fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, meanjs

I'm creating a site in which I have objects that all have a 'tags' property, which is a list of strings.

I'm creating a search functionality that filters all elements in a list. If the user enters '#something here', then I want to ONLY match the user input to the tags of each property. If the user just enters a string in the search box, then I want to search all object properties.

I have a form defined like so:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input data-ng-model="$root.searchText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#hashtag or just a string">
  </div>
</form>
```

I know that the default filter can be used in the way I want it to if I define the data-ng-model with the field I want. So if I wanted to only search tags, I'd do data-ng-model='$root.searchText.tags', and user input will only match that. If I want to search all, then I'd do data-ng-model='$root.searchText.$'.

But how can I make the model switch based on whether or not a user types in a string with '#' at the beginning or not?

I've tried creating a custom filter, but that got confusing. There should be some kind of conditional statement that either sets the model to be $root.searchText.tags or $root.searchText.$, but that's more difficult that I thought. Does anyone know how to structure that conditional statement?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you, although it might not be the best workaround.
You watch the search filter and update the lists based on your logic:

1.filter by tags if searchText starts with '#'

2.fitler by properties values if searchText do **not** starts with '#'

```
$scope.$watch('model.search', function(search){
    var tagFilter,results;
      if(search.startsWith('#')) { //handle tag filter logic
        tagFilters = search.split('#');
        console.log(tagFilters);
        results = _.filter($scope.model.lists, function(obj){
          return _.intersection(obj.tags, tagFilters).length > 0;
        });
      } else { //handle property filter logic
        results = _.filter($scope.model.lists, function (obj) {
          return _.values(obj).some(function (el) {
              return el.indexOf(search) > -1;
          });
        });
      }
        console.log(results);
      $scope.model.displayItems = results;

    }, true);
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCmvY5yKIricn7hvsK9f?p=preview)

Comment: This worked well! The only issue now is that on page load, the $scope.model.lists in my own code is actually empty and must be asynchronously queried from the database. So when the page first loads nothing is on the screen because the watch filter ran with an empty list.